# Passing Variables to a CFM form in PHP

Tags: php

I am working with a partner site to embed a form onto my site where users can login to a portal. The portal developer has granted me access to a web-login service in order for me to pass variables from my site to his.

This is the information given How can I make this work in PHP, I have a form with a checkbox, and username and password but don't quite know how to make it pass variables I am not seeing any connection on my end. And I don't know how to set it up where they are redirected to a page on my site when the reset their password any ideas?

I have done this before using a WordPress login and adding it to my main site so I know most of the basics to make it work but what I have applied so far has not worked for me. I guess I need a little nudge in the right direction to get the brain working again.

Thanks in advance.

**From the Developer**

```
I am working on a web login service that you could use and have enough done that I can 
send you the requirements.

Form Post URL: http://portal.blank.com/services/formlogin.cfm
Form variables:
portallogin - can be any value if present the following form variables are required:

errorurl - URL to be redirected to if an error occured. There will be an "error" url variable present with a human readable error string.
portalurl - (optional) URL to be redirected to if successfully logged in. if not present will be redirected to http://portal.blank.com
username - username of user
password - password of user
agreeterms - can be any value just needs to be present to authenticate

fogotpassword - can be any value if present will lookup password based on email address and password will be emailed
email - email address associated with user
returnurl - URL to be redirected to after running password lookup
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy method would be to use [Snoopy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/snoopy/), a PHP class.  A harder method (but no less effective) would be to use [PHP's cURL functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to post your data to the form.  This is assuming you're trying to keep your link to your partner's site hidden from your users.

Alternatively, you could just make a simple HTML form and set the form action to "http://portal.blank.com/services/formlogin.cfm" if you don't care that your users know you're authenticating them against some other site.  I'd use https if available.